# What is the dfference between &a[0] and a in this program?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a program below ...I have a turbo c compiler so `int` is 2 bytes..

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[3][2]={
                 {1,3},
                 {2,0},
                 {3,4}
                };
    printf("%d",(a+1));   //increments 2 bytes
        printf("%d",(&a[0]+1)); // increments 4 bytes
        printf("%d",(a[2]));
    return 0;
 }
```

What is the difference between `a+1` and `&a[0]+1` ?

Comment: why don't you check `if(a==&a[0])`

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent expresssions.

`a + 1` and `&a[0] + 1` values are the same and they are both of type `int (*)[2]`.

Note that you are not correctly printing the pointer values: use `p` conversion specifier and cast the argument to `(void *)` to print the value of a pointer:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) (a + 1)); 
printf("%p\n", (void *) (&a[0] + 1)); 
printf("%p\n", (void *) (a[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler appears to have a bug. If `a` names an array then in [most] expressions `a` and `&a[0]` should have the same type and value so the result of the `+1` should be identical in both cases.

`a+1` and `&a[0]+1` should both be equivalent to `&a[1]`.

To be strictly correct when testing this you should use `%p` as a format specifier for displaying pointer values.

Comment: they both have the same value but on incrementing ...they have different values...

Comment: @AmolSingh: yes, but they shouldn't because they also have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

`a` names the array `int a[3][2]`, so it has the type `int [3][2]`.  In the expression `a + 1` it decays to a pointer to the first element, which is therefore of type `int (*)[2]`.

In the expression `&a[0]`, `a` again decays to a pointer of type `int (*)[2]`, so `a[0]` has the type `int [2]`. The address-of operator is a special case in that it does not provoke pointer decay, so `&a[0]` has type `int (*)[2]` and has the same type and value as the decayed `a`.

At a guess, I'd speculate that your compiler is incorrectly decaying `a[0]` in `&a[0]`, so that it's giving `&a[0]` the type `int **`.  If data pointers on your platform are 4 bytes in size then that would explain the observed result.